# How to install over http in virtual manager?

Tags: 10.04, installation, virtualization, xen

I am having a situation where I can not use a CD or PxE boot or wubi to install.I need to necessarily do an http install of Ubuntu.I am basically trying to create a guest OS in a virtualization setup on Xen on a non VT hardware. On a non VT hardware the virt-manager does not allow to install from local ISO or PXE even the only option is via a URL on http://

Here is what I did:

1. Download ubuntu 10.04 32 bit ISO
2. Kept it in /var/www (apache2 is running)
3. renamed it to ubuntu.iso

   and when I reached a stage where installation begins I gave path `http://localhost/ubuntu.iso` but I got an error `any installable distribution not found.`
4. After this I did

   ```
   mkdir /var/www/sk
   mount -t iso9660 /var/www/ubuntu.iso /var/www/sk -o loop
   ```

and this time during the installation I gave path `http://localhost/sk` I was able to see the contents in browser `http://localhost/sk` which you will see in a normal CD. But beginning installation I got same error

```
ValueError: Could not find an installable distribution at 'http://localhost/sk
```

So I want to just confirm if http install is done only this way or some other way because the installation is not proceeding.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Without using an ISO, how where you able to boot the VM to begin with? You've got the loopback part right. Though I think you might have to tell the installer to use that http url as an additional mirror than specify it directly in the installer. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LocalNet

Comment: Question appears to be abandoned, if you have a similar question please ask it again.